# Saving a file from a server to local user

Tags: php, pdf

My code generates a PDF and saves to a server. the user can access a view the PDF however i wish to incorporate a save function. I have see that adding the document to the header will work, however generated code is in a separate php file and doesn't trigger a download.

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"')`

Answer (score 0):

The header is used by your browser so that it knows how to handle what it receives. This particular handler tells the browser that its receiving a document that should be downloaded, however you need to send the content of the document with [readfile](http://php.net/readfile) or any other function doing the same thing.